# Random card generation

Tags: java

I need to randomly generate three cards from array i have the array of 52 cards names from card1 to card52

```
String rank[]=new String[52];
for(int i=0;i<rank.length;i++)
{
rank[i]= "card"+i;
}
```

Now i need to select three cards from the array and it should not be repetable.

can anybody help me. actually i m doing this bt cards are repeting.
pls provide me the sollution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: String rank[]=new String[52];
  for(int i=0;i<rank.length;i++)
  {
   rank[i]= "card"+i;
  }

Comment: I'm glad we have such an active helpful community but why are we doing some kids homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an array (or even a string) and add to it whenever you select a card. That way whenever you select the second or third card you can select another one if it is in the array (or string).

Here is one way to do it... I didn't check if it works.

```
String pickedCards = ""
int totalPickedCards = 0
boolean continue = true;
for(continue) 
{
  tempVariable = pickedCard
  if (pickedCard.contains("/"+tempVariable+"/") == false) { // if you didn't already pick it then
    pickedCards = pickedCards + "/" + tempVariable + "/";
    // save the card you picked - stored in tempVariable
    ++totalPickedCards
  }
  if (totalPickedCards >= 3) { // exit loop if you have 3 cards picked
    continue = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try [Collections.shuffle(List list)](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method:

```
String rank[] = new String[52];
for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
  rank[i] = "card" + i;
}
List<String> cards = Arrays.asList(rank);
Collections.shuffle(cards);
List<String> selectedCards = cards.subList(0, 3);
```

Comment: `Collections.shuffle()` uses Fisher-Yates algorithm (or something very similar) which runs in linear time, so the difference between swapping 3 random cards and 52 random cards is relatively neglible (49 extra indexes into an array)

Comment: @matt b: I don't get your point. Using Collections.shuffle, you have to swap 52 cards to get 3 random ones. It's O(n) but n is the number of cards *in the collection* which is always 52, not the number of cards picked out - so the complexity is rather irrelevant.

Comment: @sje397 my point is that the extra work in shuffling the whole deck is pretty negligent.

Comment: @matt b: Whether it's negligible is subjective and/or context dependent, so untestable. Shuffling 3 cards with Collections.shuffle is useless; there isn't any 'extra work' - you *have* to shuffle the whole deck. The fact that Collections.shuffle runs in linear time says nothing about how it compares to other methods at the fixed scale of the question.

Answer (score 8):

If you convert your array to a `List` you can use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to randomise it.  Then if you just take the first three entries of the list you'll get three random cards with no repeats.

```
List<String> ranklist = Arrays.asList(rank);
Collections.shuffle(ranklist);
String rank1 = ranklist.get(0);
String rank2 = ranklist.get(1);
String rank3 = ranklist.get(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that might be faster than shuffling the whole array:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
int c1 = r.nextInt(52),
  c2 = r.nextInt(51),
  c3 = r.nextInt(50);
if(c2 >= c1) c2++;
if(c3 >= Math.min(c1, c2)) c3++;
if(c3 >= Math.max(c1, c2)) c3++;
System.out.println("Card 1: " + rank[c1]);
System.out.println("Card 2: " + rank[c2]);
System.out.println("Card 3: " + rank[c3]);
```

In fact, some timing tests I did using a generalised (slower) form of [this algorithm](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Iu3YRNIHDGMzE5ODA1YmItMjQ1Mi00ZGM4LWE2NWEtYTg2OTk3YzI5OTY2&hl=en_GB&authkey=CP-A1ekP) vs [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Iu3YRNIHDGYTBkODRiNzktZDllNC00MTRkLWI1NTAtNzdjZDQ3ZmU2ZDhh&hl=en_GB&authkey=CJaok94K) (screen shot [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Yg12_zYMBELOP2_qBpWFFg?feat=directlink)) show that this method is **about 3.7 times faster for 3 cards**, and in practice **faster for choosing up to 24** random cards.

To explain the algorithm to those doubting:

## Probabilities

We pick random numbers - first, one of 52. If we were to remove that card then pick another, that would be one of 51...so we're ok with the random number range of the indexes we choose.

If we were picking and removing from an array, then we just take out item at index 1, then take out item at index 2, and the same for index 3.

What I'm doing above is adjusting the indexes to have the same effect as taking the items out of the array.

For index two, we have a number that could be any number from 0 to 50. But, lets pretend we took out the card at index 6...

This means that instead of a random number spread over the range 0 to 50, we now want one equally spread over the range 0-5, and 7-51. That is still a total of 51 possibilities. We do that by adding 1 to our second index, if it is >= 6. Now we have a number over the correct range with the correct distribution and equal probability if hitting any of the allowed indexes.

The same slightly more complex logic goes for the third card: there are two spots 'missing' in the deck - so we adjust the third index to cover the available ranges. First, if it's equal to or above the first missing position, shift it up. Then if it's equal to or above the second, shift it up again. This does not bias the selection toward higher values - all we are doing is avoiding the indexes that have already been used.

There is no skew in the probabilities.

## Efficiency

It was mentioned in comments, that this algorithm and the one using `Collections.shuffle` have the same complexity (i.e., O(n)), and this method is slightly less readable. The first point to make is that this algorithm is *more* complex; i.e. to shuffle the whole array it is O(n^2). For low n, this algorithm is more efficient. And, I think the difference in *efficiency* warrants the sacrifice in readability. Compare:

**Collections.shuffle**

1. pick random number
2. remove item from list
3. insert item into list
4. repeat 51 more times

**This method**

1. pick random number
2. pick random number
3. pick random number
4. Up to 3 increments

This ignores the translation from an array to a Container necessary when using the first method. The inevitable conclusion being that this method is significantly more efficient.

*BTW - you can visualise the O(n^2) nature when you think about picking 4 cards - which requires up to 6 increments...5 cards, up to 10...6 cards, up 15...for n, (n^2 - n)/2*

## Generalising

In this exaple I've used `Math.min` and `Math.max` as a simple way to sort a list of 2 items. In the generic case (i.e. selecting 'n' [1-52 inclusive] non-repeating random cards), we need to sort a list of up to 52 items. This can be done in O(n) worst case using an insertion sort, by keeping an ordered list of selected indexes. Selecting a new random index is done by

1. Select a new random index, using `Random.nextInt(52 - selectedIndexListSize)`
2. Iterate over the sorted list, at each node incrementing our selected index if it is >= node value, stopping if it is less
3. output card at the selected index in the array
4. insert our selected index into the sorted list, at the point where we stopped

It's O(n) for each selection - but given up to 52 selections, that makes it O(n^2).

In terms of efficiency however, this algorithm is more efficient whenever m^2 < n, (or to be more precise, whenever m + (m^2-m)/2 < n) where n is 52 and m is the number of cards chosen. So this method is more efficient for picking 7 or less cards (or using the more precise calc, 9 or less), and therefore and obviously, more efficient for picking 3.

Comment: Umm, (a) That doesn't guarantee unique values. What if the generated values are, say, 10, 9, and 9. Then c2>=c1==false, no change; c3>=c1==false, no change; c3>=c2==true, increment c3, c3 is now 10, thus duplicating c1. (b) Even if you straighten that out, if it's important that each card be equally likely of being chosen, this breaks that. Once c1 is chosen, there are now 2 ways to get c1+1 -- an original draw of c1+1 or of c1 -- making that card more likely than any other.

Comment: Except it isn't as random as a shuffle; in particular it biases the selections to the high numbered cards.

Comment: @Jay - fixed point 1. But I don't know about affecting the probabilities. (1) c2 and c3 have a smaller range and (2) the point of using '>=' is to simulate the effect of just removing c1 from the options available to c2, and so on for c3. An original draw of c1+1 will get moved up to c1+2.

Comment: @msw: I don't believe it does bias the selection. It would if I had used '=='.

Comment: @aioobe: O(n) when n is 52 is a lot slower than O(n) when n is 3.

Comment: `if (any_predicate_at_all()) cx++;` biases the selection upwards.

Comment: @msw: yes, and the smaller range they are selected from biases it equally downwards.

Comment: your guesses about probability do not constitute proof; you are still mistaken and this is a bad algorithm. If in doubt, measure it.

Comment: I am not in doubt. The subsequent selections are just made from the remaining space. It's not hard to prove. It's equivalent to removing the previous choices from an array.

Comment: You are making an assertion about the correctness of a random selection algorithm based on the fact that it runs? No, I meant actual proof.

Comment: @msw: that demo compares the method of taking from an array (no cx++ as you put it) so no possible skew, to my method - and shows that the results are *always* identical. That is proof. I tried to explain further in my edit.

Comment: @Vitalii Fedorenko - if you're program was reporting mostly more that 50, that would indicate a bias *downwards*. I will try it after some sleep :)

Comment: @sje, "O(n) when n is 52 is a lot slower than O(n) when n is 3", so you're claiming that O(52) is worse than O(3)? :-) you need to read up on the big-o notation :)

Comment: @aioobe: No, which is why I didn't write that. What I did state is that doing 52 things is slower than doing 3 things, obviously implying that those things are roughly equivalent, which is true.

Comment: So you agree on that the two approaches have the same complexity?

Comment: Not since I did some timing tests and thinking, no. You can see some test classes [here](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Iu3YRNIHDGMzE5ODA1YmItMjQ1Mi00ZGM4LWE2NWEtYTg2OTk3YzI5OTY2&hl=en_GB&authkey=CP-A1ekP) (mine) and [here](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Iu3YRNIHDGYTBkODRiNzktZDllNC00MTRkLWI1NTAtNzdjZDQ3ZmU2ZDhh&hl=en_GB&authkey=CJaok94K) (Collections.shuffle). A screenshot of the timing data is [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Yg12_zYMBELOP2_qBpWFFg?feat=directlink)

Comment: Guys - shuffling an entire deck of 52 cards and then picking 3 is clearly not going to be as performant as picking 3 at random from a list with no ordering constraint (random or otherwise).  The shuffle isn't cheap, and sje397's timing graph clearly indicates this.  Shuffle is only going to be worth it when you want to a pick a larger number of cards.  Shuffle is not a good solution to this problem if you're interested in performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int randomInt;

        do {
            randomInt = random.nextInt(52);
            if (randomList.contains(new Integer(randomInt)))
                continue;
            randomList.add(randomInt);
        } while (randomList.size() < 3);
```

randomList will contain the index of the three card

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two mathematically valid ways:

1. As others have suggested, shuffle the entire array, then pick sequentially from the beginning.
2. Pick the first one at random. Then pick the second one at random. If the second is the same as the first, pick at random again. i.e. put the pick into a loop that keeps trying until it gets a value that hasn't been chosen before. For the third you have to check against the first two, etc. You may want to create a set of flags parallel to the list of cards to indicated which have been chosen, or maybe you can change a card to null after it's chosen, etc.

#1 is more efficient if you're going to use a large percentage of the cards. #2 is more efficient if you're going to use a small percentage of the cards.