# How would I write a method that rearranges cards in a deck

Tags: java

I need to split a deck of cards into two packets: the top half and the bottom half.  This new array of cards is suppose to go: first card from from the top packet, first card from bottom packet, second card from top packet, second card from bottom packet, etc.  If there are an odd number of cards then the top packet should have one more than the bottom packet.  The top of the deck is the front of the array.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the method I created to generate the deck of cards (I think it works):

```
private Card[] cards;
int value, suit;
private final int DECK_SIZE = 52;

public Deck()
    {
        int index = 0;
        cards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
        //0 = spades, 1 = hearts, 2 = clovers, 3 =diamonds
        int suits[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        //1 = Ace, 11=jack, 12=queen, 13=king
        int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        for (int suit : suits)
            for (int value : values)
            {
                cards[index] = new Card(value, suit);
                index++;
            }
    }
```

Comment: fyi they're clubs, not clovers. You haven't been eating Lucky Charms cereal lately, have you?

Comment: ...and the face cards are jack queen king, not joker queen king.

Comment: @user: Consider using an `enum` for the values.

Comment: @Jason: FYI [clovers is an alternative name for clubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit_(cards)).

Comment: This has been discussed many times before. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205321/java-card-shuffle and that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415555/random-card-generation (among many others).

Comment: @mindas: Is it clear that the user asking for a shuffle or a form of randomization?

Comment: @Dave, @user: And an `enum` for the suits too.

Comment: @Mark: point taken on the clovers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you go about doing what you say, note that a [perfect shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_shuffle) is **not** a good idea if you are looking to randomize the order of a deck:

> A perfect faro shuffle, where the cards are perfectly alternated, is considered one of the most difficult sleights of card manipulation, because it requires the shuffler to cut the deck into two equal stacks and apply just the right pressure when pushing the half decks into each other. If one manages to perform eight perfect faro out-shuffles in a row, then the deck of 52 cards will be restored to its original order. If one can do perfect in-shuffles, then 26 shuffles will reverse the order of the deck and 26 more will restore it to its original order.

---

If you want a *random* shuffle, on the other hand, the way to go is a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). From the wikipedia page:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indexes 0..n-1):
  for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
       j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
       exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

Note, however, that depending on your randomness criteria, the standard Java random number generator may not be sufficient: (also from the Wikipedia page:)

> For example, the built-in pseudorandom number generator provided by many programming languages and/or libraries may often have only 32 bits of internal state, which means it can only produce 2<sup>32</sup> different sequences of numbers. If such a generator is used to shuffle a deck of 52 playing cards, it can only ever produce a very small fraction of the 52! ≈ 2<sup>225.6</sup> possible permutations. It's impossible for a generator with less than 226 bits of internal state to produce all the possible permutations of a 52-card deck. It has been suggested[citation needed] that confidence that the shuffle is unbiased can only be attained with a generator with more than about 250 bits of state.

[Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is a well-known random number generator that would be adequate.

---

edit: for a literal answer to your original question, here's how I would probably do it (including a test method):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Shuffle {
    /* assumes input and output arrays are same length (N) */
    static public <T> void perfectShuffle(T[] input, T[] output, int N)
    {
        int itop = 0;
        int ibottom = N - (N/2);
        /* bottom has (N/2) elements; for odd N this is rounded down,
         * and the top part has 1 more element */
        int k = 0;
        while (ibottom < N)
        {
           output[k++] = input[itop++];
           output[k++] = input[ibottom++];
        } 
        // handle last element for N = odd
        if (k < N)
           output[k] = input[itop];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 19;
        String[] in = new String[N];
        String[] out = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            in[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        perfectShuffle(in, out, N);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(out));
    }
}
```

output of `main()`:

```
 [0, 10, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 4, 14, 5, 15, 6, 16, 7, 17, 8, 18, 9]
```

finally, the reason why you shouldn't use this for shuffling cards:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 52;
    String[] in = new String[N];
    String[] out = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        in[i] = Integer.toString(i);

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k)
    {
        perfectShuffle(in, out, N);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(out));

        String[] tmp = in;
        in = out;
        out = tmp;          
    }
}
```

output:

```
[0, 26, 1, 27, 2, 28, 3, 29, 4, 30, 5, 31, 6, 32, 7, 33, 8, 34, 9, 35, 10, 36, 11, 37, 12, 38, 13, 39, 14, 40, 15, 41, 16, 42, 17, 43, 18, 44, 19, 45, 20, 46, 21, 47, 22, 48, 23, 49, 24, 50, 25, 51]
[0, 13, 26, 39, 1, 14, 27, 40, 2, 15, 28, 41, 3, 16, 29, 42, 4, 17, 30, 43, 5, 18, 31, 44, 6, 19, 32, 45, 7, 20, 33, 46, 8, 21, 34, 47, 9, 22, 35, 48, 10, 23, 36, 49, 11, 24, 37, 50, 12, 25, 38, 51]
[0, 32, 13, 45, 26, 7, 39, 20, 1, 33, 14, 46, 27, 8, 40, 21, 2, 34, 15, 47, 28, 9, 41, 22, 3, 35, 16, 48, 29, 10, 42, 23, 4, 36, 17, 49, 30, 11, 43, 24, 5, 37, 18, 50, 31, 12, 44, 25, 6, 38, 19, 51]
[0, 16, 32, 48, 13, 29, 45, 10, 26, 42, 7, 23, 39, 4, 20, 36, 1, 17, 33, 49, 14, 30, 46, 11, 27, 43, 8, 24, 40, 5, 21, 37, 2, 18, 34, 50, 15, 31, 47, 12, 28, 44, 9, 25, 41, 6, 22, 38, 3, 19, 35, 51]
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 5, 13, 21, 29, 37, 45, 2, 10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50, 7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 4, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44, 1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 6, 14, 22, 30, 38, 46, 3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43, 51]
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51]
```

Comment: I'll edit to explain how to implement a random shuffle. Otherwise the question is a moot question, IMHO.

Comment: I don't see how this comes close to answering the question that the user was asking.  It's a good post for shuffling a deck of cards, but that's not what the user asked for and as the question's comments show, *that* question has been answered many times elsewhere.

Comment: @Mark: fair enough, literal answer added.

Comment: method signature should be simplified to `static public void perfectShuffle(Object[] input, Object[] output, int N)`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar (shuffling a JSONArray) in this question: [An efficient way to shuffle a JSON array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531130/an-efficient-way-to-shuffle-a-json-array-in-java)

I ended up making my own shuffle method implementing [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). For your example, it would be something like:

```
public Card[] shuffle(Card[] cards) {
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
       Random rnd = new Random();
       for (int i = cards.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Card card = cards[j];
          cards[j] = cards[i];
          cards[i] = card;
       }
       return cards;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use `Collections.shuffle`?  `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards))`.

Comment: @Mark that was my first option, but then this would avoid making a List from the array and back to the array again. In the question I quoted, I asked about efficiency but nobody gave me an answer to that. I even posted it on code review, and the only comment was about using generics (which is also very true). I understand that this array is not a JSONArray, but the question is similar and the algorithm is quite simple to just do it that way. I don't know how many decks there will be shuffling simultaneously either.

Comment: One thing that's not efficient about this approach is that it copies the Cards just to swap them. That should never be needed, even if it were Card a mutable type (which it certainly should not be).  Just reassign the card instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Well, looking at the latest comments and reading the edited question, it's obvious that I misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to substitute a non-perfect shuffle, try Collections.shuffle().  Your code would look something like this:

```
List card_list = Arrays.asList(cards);
Collections.shuffle(card_list);
```

or as @Mark Peters points out, the more concise:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
```

Comment: 1) You should use generics, and 2) you don't need to do the `toArray` line.  The comment I posted on @Aleadam's answer is all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was actually off looking into whether the new List was backed by the original Array and then noticed you were *way* ahead of me.

Comment: yeah...I need to learn to look at the timestamp of a question before I comment :-).